# Getting MIDI timecode/clock from MIXXX beat detection

Tags: software, daw, dj

Does anyone on here know if `mixxx` can somehow generate MIDI timecode/clock information for jack from its detected beat of the current playback. As applications like `ardour`, `qtraktor`, `seq24` and other sequencers can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mixxx includes a “MIDI for light” script that can send MIDI clock output for controlling lights or other MIDI synced hardware or software

See https://mixxx.org/wiki/doku.php/midi_clock_output